# Why is Germany not able to read data from the Boeing 737 MAX black boxes?

Tags: boeing-737, accident-investigation, flight-data-recorder, germany

It is my understanding that Germany [stated it does not have the capacity to read the new software](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-ethiopia-airplane/germany-will-not-look-at-crashed-boeing-737-max-black-box-canada-grounds-jets-idUSKBN1QU15W), declining Ethiopia's request:

> "The French announcement resolved uncertainty over the fate of the two
>   recorders after Germany’s BFU said it had declined a request to handle
>   them because it could not process the new type of recorder used on the
>   737 MAX jets, in service since 2017."

Does anyone know which requirements were missing?

Answer (score 7):

[This news article](https://www.afp.com/de/nachrichten/3966/us-flugaufsicht-begruendet-flugverbot-fuer-boeing-737-max-mit-neuen-indizien-doc-1ek2av5) (in German) includes a mention that the black box was using newer software than the BFU has the capability to read out:

> Das Gerät habe eine neue Software, die an der BFU nicht ausgelesen
>   werden könne.

Comment: Thank you. That is what I was curious about -- as to why they are not able. Contrary to France.

Comment: @ted don't forget to mark nengel's answer as *accepted*!:)